# How can I open an editable pdf?

Tags: gnome, pdf, evince, adobe-reader

I am not able to open this file with Evince or Okular, but I can open this file with Reader on Windows.

Here's is a picture:

[image: A photo of a computer screen]

Comment: I would assume all is answered in this topic https://askubuntu.com/questions/162037/how-to-edit-pdfs

Comment: Here is a related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/878756/why-does-ubuntu-not-ship-with-a-way-to-fill-in-pdf-forms

Comment: Try `masterpdfeditor`.

Answer (score 0):

[LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) should work well for this. 
It should be the default in Ubuntu, but in case you don't have it installed:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```